# Laptop USB-C stopped being able to accept charging or charge phones

Tags: 20.04, power-management, acer, usb-c, charging

On my Acer Swift 5 (SF514-53T), after working ok for a long time, its only USB-C port suddenly stopped accepting power from a charger.

It also stopped being able to power rapid charging of phones from it (possibly even all charging from it).

Answer (score 2):

**Solved by "physically" disconnecting and reconnecting the battery.**

On the Acer laptop, there is a tiny hole at the bottom which hides a button that can be pressed with a paper clip. When pressed this disconnects the battery module, so no need to *open the laptop*.

Some laptops apparently have this as a BIOS triggerable setting. I imagine some laptops still have a detachable battery, too, which my button imitates.

This solved the issue, and the USB C port works fine now.